# Can't see /proc/scsi/sg folder in the Yocto file system

Tags: yocto, scsi

I'm using a Yocto image on an iMX6 SoC ev-board and I would like to write a C code to access the USB storage device via sg driver.

Since I need to access the logical blocks of the storage directly instead of transferring through kernel buffer, I attempt to change the ***/proc/scsi/sg/allow_dio*** flag on the pseudo file system which introduced by the document [Linux Version 3 SCSI Generic Driver](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/s_packet.html), but I can't find the folder ***/proc/scsi/sg*** in the file system.

I think the ***sg*** module has been loaded on the running system because I can operate to the USB storage with the indirect method (but that's not appropriate to my demand).

Is there a alternate way to enable the direct IO or how to make /proc/scsi/sg appears?

Answer (score 0):

It has been moved to `/sys/module/sg/parameters/allow_dio`